# Installing ROS packages on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, ros

I was trying to install `ros-kinetic-controller-manager` and `ros-kinetic-teleop-twist-keyboard` on my Raspberry Pi. However, it showed an error that the packages could not be found. Is there a way to install it from an external source onto my Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 0):

Try in your console

```
sudo apt-get install [package]
```

Comment: I've tried that. It shows: E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-controller-manager.

Comment: Maybe you have to update your linux distribution before? By sudo apt-get update